# Integrating multiple apps using Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management

I have multiple webservices and I would like to expose them as a single API endpoint. So basically I am looking at creating an API facade which internally calls multiple backend APIs sequentially. Is this possible in Azure APIM or is there any other offering in Azure for achieving the same

Comment: I need bit more info. Are these APIs are hosted on different APP servers or these all one program and hosted on single APP Server ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that come to mind:

1. Azure API Management will allow you to do that and more. In its core it's an API gateway that accepts requests and passes them on. From that you get analytics, caching, policy engine to augment request/response, load-balancing, backend aggregation e.t.c.
2. Azure APP Gateway is a simpler offering that is tailored more towards routing and load balancing.